# SDN: what is replacement of __types__ in Spring data neo4j 3.1.4

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Why the `NamedIndexRepository` in Spring Data Neo4j 3.1.x is depricated ? Is there any way to create `__types__` index to create cypher query like this:

```
Start root=node:__types__(className="a.b.c.XYZ") return root
```

Seems its no longer supported in new SDN. Any otherway around to achieve this ?

**Update**
This [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_typerepresentationstrategy) show that we can choose to use legacy index strategy. Thanks stefan and tstorm. Now again question arises, is there any performance issue if not using typical `__types__(className="")` what if I use like this: `Start root=node(*)....` ?

Comment: You might benefit from my blog post about SDN 3 migration: http://javaprogress.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/migrating-to-spring-data-neo4j-3-0/

Comment: Thank you @tstorms :) that helped me. `TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory` was the solution. also I found this http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.neo4j.user/19065 and followed by this one http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_typerepresentationstrategy

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j added the notion of labels back in 2.0. Labels are the recommended way to group certain nodes, aka nodes having the same class. For details check out the blog post at http://neo4j.com/blog/spring-data-neo4j-progress-update-sdn-3-neo4j-2/.

Comment: Thank you. I already seen this but didn't get a clear picture of implementation or usage. Can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples?